# Is File.ReadAllText thread safe?

Tags: c#, web-services, file-io, task-parallel-library

Specifically will spawning a thread using the TPL `Task.Factory.StartNew`:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
       File.ReadAllText(@"thisFile.txt");
});
```

Causing any issues, etc? There doesn't appear to be any mention of thread safety on the [MSDN resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It's in a SOAP web service environment.

Ps Please, I don't want to know about the pro's and cons of using a Task in a web environment. I'm fully aware of these issues, *please*, just take it for granted that in my case this model is justified, thanks.

Comment: [What](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx) is _thread safe_ in your definition? The other threads cannot interfere with the reading. But the file is not locked, so if some other process (or thread) is writing the file at the very same moment, you're going to have a trouble.

Comment: It's all just reading, no writing is performed on the file at all. If the file was overwritten this would be a manual task and would happen rarely.

Comment: I think that if Jon & Marc answered your question you can 1. Sleep peacefully at night. 2. Know you've gotten your answer :)

Comment: _Overwritten rarely_ sounds like _race condition_ for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's fine - assuming nothing's writing to the file at the same time, in which case you may not be able to open the file (or might see partial writes).

As per the [documentation of `File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.File.aspx):

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

(Not that there can be any instance methods, as it's a static class...)

Answer (score 11):

Yes, that will be thread-safe in itself; however, it is still subject to the usual rules of the file-system: concurrent access to the same file depends on which flags were used by the competing handles. If any handle has it marked for exclusive access, then it will fail with an IO-related exception.

Answer (score 4):

There is actually no such thing as "thread safe" without defining what operations are used.

If all the threads (and processes!) are just reading the file in either way, the read is safe. If however some of the threads (or another processes) is writing into the file, you might get a half-up-to-date information, you never know how the writing is organized.

For a more fail-proof access, you could use

```
using (var s = new FileStream(..., FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
using (var tr = new StreamReader(s))
{
    content = tr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `File.ReadAllText` doesn't state anything and therefore doesn't guarantee anything about locking.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way similar to what Vlad proposed. I'm using the FileShare option of Read, so other streams can read from the same file.

```
byte[] buffer;
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("pathGoesHere", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fs.Length);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I am late on this answer. I also like to know if it is thread safe. So, I tested and find that File.ReadAllText is thread safe if all read is from File.ReadAllText.  I tested with following code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestingFileReadAllText
{
    class Program
    {
        static int i=0;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for(int i =0;i<10000;i++)
            {
                Task.Run(ReadFile);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(20000);
            Console.WriteLine("Completed Successfully");
        }

        static void ReadFile()
        {
            int j = Interlocked.Increment(ref i);
            string s = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\resutl.htm");
            Console.WriteLine($"Successfully {j} read: {s.Substring(0, 10)}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of sleeping with `Thread.Sleep(20000)` and hoping that 20 seconds will be enough, you could put all the `Task.Run` tasks in a list or array, and wait them with `Task.WaitAll`.