# strange async or non async controller action behavior when sending email mvc 5

Tags: c#, email, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await

I have an async action in a controller that look like this

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(MerchantRegistrationViewModel merchantRegistrationViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Some code

        //SendMail
        EmailManager em = new EmailManager("MerchantVerify.htm",merchant,"Verify Email");
        await em.SendEmailAsync();


        db.Merchants.Add(merchant);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Success");

    }          
}
```

The code in the method `em.SendEmailAsync()`

```
public async Task SendEmailAsync()
{
    GetEmailTemplate();

    var emailBody = BuildEmailBodyForVerifyMerchant();

    var emailToSend = BuildEmailMessage(emailBody, subject);

    var client = new SmtpClient();
    await client.SendMailAsync(emailToSend);
}
```

The problem I have noticed is with the method `GetEmailTemplate()` which contains this code block

```
private void GetEmailTemplate()
{
    //Tried Option 1
    //mailBody = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/Content/MailText/" + mailTemplate));

    //Tried Option 2 
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/Content/MailText/" + mailTemplate), FileMode.Open))
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        mailBody = sr.ReadToEnd(); 
    }

}
```

If I comment this code block and I change the action to async or non async I get the email sent. If I uncomment any of the options mail is never received. I don't get any errors.

I suspect is has something to do with the way I am reading the template  file.

```
public class EmailManager
{
    private string mailTemplate;
    private Merchant merchant;
    private string mailBody = string.Empty;
    private string subject;

    public EmailManager()
    {

    }

    public EmailManager(string mailTemplate, Merchant merchant, string subject)
    {
        this.mailTemplate = mailTemplate;
        this.merchant = merchant;
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    private void GetEmailTemplate()
    {
        //Get Mail Text Path
        //mailBody = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/Content/MailText/" + mailTemplate));
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/Content/MailText/" + mailTemplate),FileMode.Open ,FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            mailBody = sr.ReadToEnd(); // 1
        }           
    }


    private string BuildEmailBodyForVerifyMerchant()
    {
        //Replace Custom Variables for Email Body
        Uri url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
        string UrlLink = url.OriginalString.Replace(url.PathAndQuery, "");
        merchant.ProviderUserKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        UrlLink = String.Concat(UrlLink, "/");
        var verifyUrl = UrlLink + "business/verify/" + merchant.ProviderUserKey.ToString();

        //replace variables 
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("~userLastName~", merchant.Name);
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("~name~", String.Format("{0} {1}", merchant.FirstName, merchant.LastName));
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("~companyName~", merchant.Name);
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("~dateOfRegistration~", merchant.DateOfRegistration.Value.ToShortDateString());
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("~verifyUrl~", verifyUrl);
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("~email~", merchant.Email);

        return mailBody;
    }

    private MailMessage BuildEmailMessage(string body, string subject)
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

        msg.From = new MailAddress("no-reply@mydomain.com");
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(merchant.Email.ToString()));           
        msg.Subject = subject;
        msg.Body = body;

        return msg;
    }


    public async Task SendEmailAsync()
    {
        GetEmailTemplate();

        var emailBody = BuildEmailBodyForVerifyMerchant();

        var emailToSend = BuildEmailMessage(emailBody, subject);

        var client = new SmtpClient();
        await client.SendMailAsync(emailToSend);
    }


}
```

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19976673/11683) change anything?

Comment: Your phrasing is a little confusing (to me anyway), so just to be clear - are you saying if you comment out the `GetEmailTemplate();` line, the mail sends, and if not, it doesn't?

Comment: @sellotape either the line or the code in that method.

Comment: @GSerg trying your suggested link.

Comment: @GSerg Nothing changed. :(

Comment: Did you try `FileShare.Read`?

Comment: @GSerg I just tired the FileShare.Read that also did not send the mail. please note also whichever way the file content is being read, but email still not sent.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a place somewhere where you call an `async` method without `await`?

Comment: What is the purpose of this method anyways? It returns void, so any work it does is just discarded.

Comment: @ChrisPratt  it sets a private property mailBody in the EmailManager class  where the SendEmailAsync resides.

Comment: Got it. Are you sure this is all the code in play? You didn't leave anything out? There's really nothing here that would cause the email not to be sent.  It's either going to fail reading the file, which would raise an exception or execution will pass back to the calling method. Are you sure you're not swallowing any exceptions, via an errant try/catch somewhere?

Comment: Bear in mind also that the exception may be being swallowed by something not even related to this code. Something in how you handle errors with the website, an HTTP Module, etc. could be swallowing the exception after it bubbles up.

Comment: @ChrisPratt updated with my Emailmanager class. The strangest thing I experienced. Even if I pasted the entire line of code in my controller action without my EmailManager class it  behaves the same way as previously explained.

Comment: I'm going with reading the file is raising an exception but that exception is being swallowed somehow, somewhere. Nothing else makes sense.

Comment: put some try/catches in places to see exceptions?

Comment: @PeterRitchie after swarming my code with try/catches every where possible no exception was thrown. So I decided to check again; i commented reading the template out and voila got a mail in my inbox [link](https://snag.gy/NjPlhe.jpg)

Comment: @CrateDuke - is every attribute of `emailToSend` identical both ways, just before you call `client.SendMailAsync()`?

Comment: @sellotape if I understand you correctly they are the same, nothing changes,  values are also maintained.

Comment: @CrateDuke - they must be at least _somewhat_ different, as the one way your `mailBody` is empty and the other way it's not?  I wonder if it is sending but some spam filter is filtering them out?  Try install smtp4dev (quick and easy) on your machine and see what it reports when you send.

Comment: @sellotape I followed your suggestion and installed smtp4dev, i simulated multiple times on different internal servers the emails were all delivered. Using both the suggested refactoring and my old code, emails delivered perfectly. I decided to change the smtp server I was using to send the earlier mails and finally with both codes  the emails were received. I don't want to conclude it has to do with my initial smtp server because I use `UserManager.SendEmailAsync()` to send user verification emails and that works fine only this time I don't use a template.

Comment: @CrateDuke - mysterious...  While you're at it, both `MailMessage` and `SmtpClient` are `IDisposable`s and you should dispose them.  If you're sending only a few emails, just stick the `SmtpClient` in a `using`; if lots you can re-use it (and eventually dispose it), but you should definitely dispose of each `MailMessage` (stick it in a `using` too).

Comment: @sellotape the mystery is still not solved. I am currently trying to find out what is happening with my mail service provider  support team.  Considering they host both services, one which worked and the current which doesn't. We are still no where near a solution; they did mention though, about spam issues on that particular network service. Temporarily, I have resorted to SendGrid api whiles we investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a refactor of the `EmailManager` given the provided example in the OP. 
The methods were refactored to better express their dependencies and hopefully help in isolating what may be causing the problem in the `GetEmailTemplate` method.

```
public interface IEmailManager {
    Task SendEmailAsync();
}

public class EmailManager : IEmailManager {
    private string mailTemplate;
    private Merchant merchant;
    private string subject;

    public EmailManager(string mailTemplate, Merchant merchant, string subject) {
        this.mailTemplate = mailTemplate;
        this.merchant = merchant;
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    private async Task<string> GetEmailTemplateAsync(string mailTemplate) {
        var mailBody = String.Empty;
        //Get Mail Text Path
        var path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/Content/MailText/" + mailTemplate);

        //mailBody = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/Content/MailText/" + mailTemplate));
        using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs)) {
            mailBody = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
        }

        return mailBody;
    }


    private string BuildVerifyEmailBodyForMerchant(string mailBody, Merchant merchant) {
        //Replace Custom Variables for Email Body
        var url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
        var urlLink = url.OriginalString.Replace(url.PathAndQuery, "");
        merchant.ProviderUserKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        urlLink = String.Concat(urlLink, "/");
        var verifyUrl = urlLink + "business/verify/" + merchant.ProviderUserKey.ToString();

        //replace variables 
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("~userLastName~", merchant.Name);
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("~name~", String.Format("{0} {1}", merchant.FirstName, merchant.LastName));
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("~companyName~", merchant.Name);
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("~dateOfRegistration~", merchant.DateOfRegistration.Value.ToShortDateString());
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("~verifyUrl~", verifyUrl);
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("~email~", merchant.Email);

        return mailBody;
    }

    private MailMessage BuildEmailMessage(string body, string subject, Merchant merchant) {
        var msg = new MailMessage();

        msg.From = new MailAddress("no-reply@mydomain.com");
        msg.To.Add(merchant.Email.ToString());
        msg.Subject = subject;
        msg.Body = body;

        return msg;
    }

    public async Task SendEmailAsync() {
        var emailTemplate = await GetEmailTemplateAsync(mailTemplate);

        var emailBody = BuildVerifyEmailBodyForMerchant(emailTemplate, merchant);

        var emailToSend = BuildEmailMessage(emailBody, subject, merchant);

        using (var client = new SmtpClient()) {
            await client.SendMailAsync(emailToSend);
        }
    }
}
```